# Binding to parent

Tags: jquery

I have a plugin where i'm binding events on focus and focusout..

```
textarea
     .unbind('.dynSiz')
     .bind('keyup.dynSiz', updateSize)
     .bind('keydown.dynSiz', updateSize)
     .bind('focus',updateSize)
     .bind('focusout',resetSize)
```

or even document.click - > resetSize should get called...

I want the focus out to be applied to the parent instead of textarea. How can this be done ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this:

```
textarea.parent().bind('focus',updateSize);
```

But it is important to keep in mind how your updateSize function works.  If it uses `$(this)` to change the size of the textarea (which is what I am assuming is being resized), then it won't function properly if it is calling from the parent (`$(this)` would be the parent, not the textarea).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) function in jQuery:

```
textarea.parent().bind('focus', updateSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the event to the parent, as pointed by Simeon and Andrew, but remember also to correctly assign `tabIndex` to the element if it's not a standard focusable one (`input`, `select`, `a` ...).

See also:

http://api.jquery.com/focus/

http://snook.ca/archives/accessibility_and_usability/elements_focusable_with_tabindex

http://davidwalsh.name/tabindex-focus